# Automatically generate Retrofit Types

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, retrofit

I'm a newie using Retrofit, and I was seraching for a automatic way to generate the class types for consume a rest web service with retrifit becouse as far as I've seen I'm suposed map all the objects that returns the server.

Specifically I want to work with a Endpoint Django REST framework 2.3.14 with a lot of elements by each method, Thats why I want to generate in an automatic way the element types.

I've seen some with JAX-RS but I'm not sure it works with django Rest Services.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [website]http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org, very useful to convert JSON to POJOs...